# processor(s) statistics that is one day old

Tags: bash, proc

I already know how to use `grep -w cpu /proc/stat` in order to get the cpu stats and identify the user mode. Percentage wise, I just divide it my the total time from the `/proc/uptime`.

However, how can I get it for the last 24 hours. I know the `find -mtime m` and I was thinking it could be used since `/proc/stat` is a folder after all..

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There are several ways to get at this information. The first that comes to mind is to use `mpstat` from a cronjob that would log the info to a file. A command like this would write a summary line after 24 hours.

#### mpstat

```
$ mpstat 86400 1
Linux 3.12.6-200.fc19.x86_64 (greeneggs.bubba.net)  01/22/2014  _x86_64_    (4 CPU)

06:37:16 PM  CPU    %usr   %nice    %sys %iowait    %irq   %soft  %steal  %guest  %gnice   %idle
06:37:21 PM  all   20.72    0.00    2.82    2.42    0.35    0.10    0.00    0.00    0.00   73.59
Average:     all   20.72    0.00    2.82    2.42    0.35    0.10    0.00    0.00    0.00   73.59
```

You can use various switches to `mpstat` to control exactly what shows up in the output.

#### sar

With `sar` you can have this running all the time on your system as a service. It will collect performance data which you can then extract reports from at a later date.

```
$ sar -f /var/log/sa/sa13 1200 -s 00:00:00 -e 23:59:59
```

Will produce a report of CPU usage from 12AM (midnight) until 23:59:59 (end of the day) in 20 minute increments (1200 seconds = 20 min.).

This is just an example of the type of output it will produce.

```
$ sar -u 5 2
Linux 3.12.6-200.fc19.x86_64 (greeneggs.bubba.net)  01/22/2014  _x86_64_    (4 CPU)

06:49:47 PM     CPU     %user     %nice   %system   %iowait    %steal     %idle
06:49:52 PM     all     21.44      0.00      3.08      1.16      0.00     74.32
06:49:57 PM     all     21.47      0.00      3.83      3.78      0.00     70.92
Average:        all     21.46      0.00      3.45      2.47      0.00     72.62
```

You can do a lot more with `sar`, this is just an example.

Comment: `mpstat` is exactly what I'm looking for! I asusme the 1 indicates One day, but what does the first parameter do? (long number)

Comment: @Atieh - `mpstat` will report the average for 86400 (1 days worth of seconds - 60*60*24). The 1 means to report this 1 time. You could have it be longer, say 7, it would report a days avgs. 7 times (1 week).

Comment: yeah I just figured this out from the manual second paragraph from description. Interval in seconds and count is the number of reports! Sweet. Thanks!

Comment: btw, is it normal that it takes some time? My system has been 2 days on since booting..

Comment: @Atieh - which, `mpstat` or `sar`? mpstat will only print a value every 24 hours, `sar` typically runs every 10 min. collecting logs, but it would take a day or 2 to collect enough data to report on 24 hr. time periods.

Comment: omg, I just understood, by the time it ends it shall provide me with the info in the past 24 hours. brilliant...

Answer (score 1):

It is not readily available.

You could use something like collectd to [collect](http://collectd.org) those stats in rrd format for you. Then if graphs are not good enough, [rrdxport](http://oss.oetiker.ch/rrdtool/doc/rrdxport.en.html) can help you extract numerical reports.

Comment: That's also something that `sar` (from `sysstat` on Debian) or `atop` typically log (and you can query the information from them).

Comment: Actually, I want everything to be done in bash (built-in). The links you gave me act like API's and I don't want to use them.